# NERDCommenter: Giving me js comments in an html file

Tags: vim

I am editing an html file but when I invoke the NERD commenter it is adding js comments (`/*...*/`) rather than html ones (`<!-- ... -->`).  I have just installed the latest version (2.3.0) and am using vim 7.3.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

EDIT: Digging into this more, I found in the source code of NERD_commenter.vim a list of all the supported filetypes.  Oddly, xhtml and html do not appear on the list:

```
\ 'htmlcheetah': { 'left': '##' },
\ 'htmldjango': { 'left': '<!--','right': '-->', 'leftAlt': '{#', 'rightAlt': '#}' },
\ 'htmlos': { 'left': '#', 'right': '/#' },
```

I feel this cannot be right somehow.  Also, bonus question: Assuming you get html comments to work, can this plugin detect when the cursor is between `<script>` tags and change the comment to js comments when it is?

Comment: If you run `:set ft=html` and then try doing it, does it work then?

Comment: @Jonah did you find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging into the NERD-commenter code, it seems that when the filetype is not in it's list, it extracts it from a vim option named `&commentstring`. My guess would be that some other plugin/configurations has changed `&commentstring` for html files(probably to better support javascript comments).

Comment: Idan, thanks for your reply.  Makes sense.  So the best solution would be to manually add html and xhtml to the filetype list, correct?  Also, do you have an answer to the bonus question in my edit?

Comment: Yes, you should add them manually. Trying to fix `&commentstring` might break whatever changed it in the first place. Note that you can use `g:NERDCustomDelimiters` to add filetypes to NERD-commenter without editing it's sources.

Comment: Idan, how would that work?  I just searched the plugin source for NERDCustomDelimiters and found nothing.  Are you sure that's the correct name?  Thanks.

Comment: As for the bonus question - you might be able to use the syntax highlighting for that. `synstack(line('.'),col('.'))` will return a list of the syntax elements. 199 is the ID of the javascript syntax element. If you hook a function to the `CursorMoved` and `CursorMovedI` events, you can use it to automatically switch between regular and alternate delimiters, where one will be for HTML and the other for JS.

Answer (score 0):

As of [the following PR to add hooks](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter/pull/249), NERDCommenter allows one to configure a comment style that is specific to the language block within the file.

This was built to support `.vue` files that, not unlike regular HTML files, have a `<template>` (html) block, a `<script>` and a `<style>` block, each requiring a unique commenting syntax.

You can find the `vue` sample implementation in [the Hooks section of the docs](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter/blob/057f6150bdb11124bcb63e85f5445fae47f383c3/doc/NERD_commenter.txt#L396-L423). Should you choose to do so, it may help guide you in writing one for framework-agnostic HTML files.